# Using a PHP if statement to produce a hidden input field

Tags: php, html

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    Please select which criteria you would like to search by:
        <form name="form" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="criteria" value="Author">Author<br>
    <input type="radio" name="criteria" value="Title">Title<br>
    <input type="radio" name="criteria" value="Price">Price<br>
             <input type="Submit" name='submit' id="search-submit" value="Submit" /></p>
        </form>
        <?php
        $authorstatus = 'unchecked';
        $titlestatus = 'unchecked';
        $pricestatus = 'unchecked';

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $criteria = $_POST['criteria'];
            if($criteria == 'Author')
            {
                $authorstatus = 'checked';
            }
            if($criteria == 'Title')
            {
                $titlestatus = 'checked';
            }
            if($criteria == 'Price')
            {
                $pricestatus = 'checked';
            }
        }
        if($authorstatus == 'checked')
        {
            echo "<form name="form1" method="post">";
            echo "<input type='text' name='name' id='name' /><br />";
            echo "</form>";
        }
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

I am trying to use PHP to produce a field for input based upon if the user chooses to search by Author, Title, or Price. Right now, with the 3 echo lines of html inside PHP the program produces nothing but a blank page. Is there a way to do this with just PHP and HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to properly echo the HTML string.

```
echo "<form name="form1" method="post">";
```

This line will break the string as you are using double quotes for both string and attribute values. Change that line to

```
echo "<form name='form1' method='post'>";
```

Comment: i saw an answer had been made just as i was about to say the same :)

Comment: Thanks! It's always the smallest things. I will pick this answer as the best in T-Minus 7 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $criteria = $_POST['criteria'];
            if($criteria == 'Author')
            {
                $authorstatus = 'checked';
            }
            if($criteria == 'Title')
            {
                $titlestatus = 'checked';
            }
            if($criteria == 'Price')
            {
                $pricestatus = 'checked';
            }
        /*}*/ // <---  remove this
        if($authorstatus == 'checked')
        {
            echo "<form name='form1' method='post'>"; // <--- correct this 
            echo "<input type='text' name='name' id='name' /><br />";
            echo "</form>";
        }
        } // <-- It should be here..
```